# How to unescape text in Oracle APEX TextArea

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am reading data in from Oracle which has double quotes in it.  The TextArea is rending the output with:

```
&quot;
```

I can't see a way to "unescape" the characters to show the quotes on the page item.

Also, this doesn't work in the dynamic action which populates it:

```
SELECT UTL_URL.UNESCAPE(COMMENTS) FROM T_DQ_RULE WHERE ID = :P2_DQ_RULE_ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is test case:

```
create table a1_test (text clob);

insert into a1_test values ('This is "some text" for test');
```

Page item (type is TextArea) gets its value in Load Page dynamic action which sets item's value via SQL query (it returns only one row)

When page runs, result is as you described (left hand side of the screenshot). If you turn dynamic action's **Escape special characters** property off, then it looks OK (right hand side):

[image]

Comment: It works!! Didn't realise escape characters was on the DA. Cheers!

Comment: Sure did, thanks a million - was looking for it on the page item